# Is it possible to close Google Maps navigation from your app?

Tags: android, google-maps

My app launches Google Maps navigation. Is it possible to close the Google Maps navigation service from my app?

Comment: I think it is not possible, and should not be possible since any app will be able to close other app. It would be a security issue.

Comment: The Android security model doesn't allow that. why not use the sdk to embed maps inside your app? Then everything will be under your control.

Answer (score 0):

> My app launches Google Maps navigation. Is it possible to close the Google Maps navigation service from my app?

If you targeting rooted device then you can try to grab Google Maps' notification Pending Intent and use it but other than that I guess that Google Maps does not allow any external apps to command, therefore there's no i.e. public API you are looking for. As an exercise you may peek GM's Manifest file, but even something can be found there, I'd be surprised seeig no `android:permission="signature"` around).

Comment: Are you sure you can achieve that ??

Comment: Well, on **rooted** device you mostly can achieve anything :) In this case it's easier as GMaps will give you the intent as it exposes "Close" button in its notification.

Comment: Can you give me some hints too google for? Cause I'm trying to archive the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! That is a nice question.

From your application you can't  close/force stop the other application which is installed in the device (If you add that type of hack in the application using NDK, Your playstore account will be blocked by playstore).

I did similar type of hack to handle homebutton callback using NDK. Interesting part is, Playstore blocked my application as well as my playstore account!!!

Comment: Mind quoting the reason they gave you?